# Avoiding substitution of expressions archetype:create-from-project

Tags: java, maven-3, archetypes

Hey,
could please anybody tell me how to avoid substitution of  some expressions in a project when creating an archetype from it via archetype:create-from-project ?

for instance it substitutes all  appearances of "1.0" expressions in the project with `${version}`

if programmer creates the archetype from project of verion 1.0 `<version>1.0</version>` , then for instance header of an xml file

`<?xml version="1.0"?>`

changes to

```
<?xml version="1.0-SNAPSHOT"?>
```

.... because there was `<?xml version="${version}"?>`  in the archetype resources and users entered 1.0-SNAPSHOT as a project version

Also, is it possible to supply more arguments when creating project from the archetype? In addition to groupId, artifactId, package and version ?

Comment: I get this in Java files too: if I have a variable `int x = 1.0` it gets munged into `int x = ${version}` I don't know the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `-Darchetype.filteredExtentions=extension1,extension2,...` to your `mvn` command to tell maven which file extensions to include in its velocity substitutions. If you make a list of all of your file extensions and leave off `xml`, it should skip over them. You can do `-Darchetype.filteredExtentions` if `xml` is the only file type in your project.